# Sources of Fiqh from Madhabs

Tags: fiqh, madhhab, usool-ul-fiqh

Within the sunni branch of Islam, there are the 4 major Madhabs (Hanafi, Shafii, Maliki and Hanbali). My question is, is there a book or compilation of sources for each and every fiqh draw by Imam Abu Hanifa RA. For example, for every fiqh, e.g. Wudu, Salaat, Ghusl, there must be several sources which the Imam has used to arrive at a conclusion, is there any such complication for each and every fiqh for each school (Hanafi Preferably), What i'm looking isn't only a book of fiqh from a particular madhab, but i'm looking for a book where for each fiqh, it mentions the Quran Verse and/or collection of hadiths from which fiqh was derived, is there any such book, can I get some references ?

Comment: Of course you will find books with the evidences of the madhhab for each of the 4 madhhabs. You should be aware that the opinion of the madhab must not necessary be the opinion of the founder. Madhhabs have developped with the time.

Comment: There is a book called Taleemul Haq which tells you all the 5 pillars in detail including nikah, qurbani and zakat etc. It is from the Hanafi view.

Comment: What i'm looking isn't only a book of fiqh from a particular madhab, but i'm looking for a book where for each fiqh, it mentions the Quran Verse and/or collection of hadiths from which fiqh was derived, is there any such book, can I get some references ?

Comment: @Noor see this https://archive.org/details/NurAl-idah-TheLightOfClarification (Hanafi )

Comment: If i've got you right you look for a book on fiqh al-'ibaadaat (worship) according the 4 madhhabs with their evidencesis this correct?

Comment: @Medi1Saif, exactly together with their evidences !!

Comment: @Faqirah, thanks for the reference, but i did went through it, the evidences isn't very clear and the evidences are in fact what im looking for

Comment: When it comes to the at least 4 madhabs there are modern books. Else al-Istidhkar of ibn 'Abdalbarr and bidayat al mujtahid of ibn Rushd may cover at least 3 madhabs as both authors didn't consider Imam Ahmad a faqih.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, Jazak Allah bro, I shall look for these books

Comment: In that case the tag osol al fiqh is a bad fit, as osol is a science that concentrate about how a scholar of a madhhab concludes a ruling and the tools he need to excel.